# Find the field that $\mathbb{Z}_7[x,y]/\langle y-2x^2, 4xy + y +1 \rangle$ is isomorphic to

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

See the title. Here the set $\mathbb{Z}_7 = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ is considered a ring with the obvious operations $+$ and $\cdot$; and $I := \langle y-2x^2, 4xy + y + 1 \rangle$ is an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}_7[x,y]$.
My idea was to show in two steps that:
$$ \mathbb{Z}_7[x,y]/I \cong \mathbb{Z}_7[x] / J \cong \mathbb{F}_{7^3}, $$
where $J := \langle x^3+2x^2+1 \rangle$.

The first isomorphism is true (on an intuitive level) because $y + I = 2x^2 + I$, so that:
$$(4xy + y + 1) + I = (8x^3 + 2x^2 + 1) + I = (x^3 + 2x^2 + 1) + I $$
To see why the second isomorphism holds, we need a bit more work. We know that $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]/\langle x^3 + 2x^2 + 1 \rangle$ is a field, because $x^3 + 2x^2 + 1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_7$ (since no $x \in \mathbb{Z}_7$ is a root and its degree is 3). Now, "division" by $\langle x^3 + 2x^2 + 1 \rangle$ effectively gets rid of every polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]$ of degree 3 or higher. We can reduce a polynomial of degree $\geq$ 3 to degree $\leq$ 2 by iteratively using the relation $x^3 = -2x^2-1 = 5x^2 + 6$. Moreover, every polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]$ of degree $\leq$ 2 has a distinct representation in $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]/\langle x^3 + 2x^2 + 1 \rangle$. This means that $|\mathbb{Z}_7[x]/\langle x^3 + 2x^2 + 1 \rangle| = 7^3$, and hence this field must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{7^3}$.

I would like some tips on how to approach the details. Especially for the first isomorphism: I wanted to use the first isomorphism theorem to prove this. To this end, I used the ringmorphism:
$$\varphi : \mathbb{Z}_7[x,y] \to \mathbb{Z}_7[x]/J : p(x,y) \mapsto p(x,2x^2) + J$$
Then, I showed that $\ker(\varphi) = I$ and $\varphi(\mathbb{Z}_7[x,y]) = \mathbb{Z}_7[x]/J$. The first isomorphism theorem then tells us that $\mathbb{Z}_7[x,y]/\ker(\varphi) \cong \varphi(\mathbb{Z}_7[x,y])$, which is the desired result. I worked it out and it seems to be OK, but going through the details of the proof was rather cumbersome and I figured there should be an easier way.
The second isomorphism I think is pretty much proved already with the rough sketch I made earlier, I just need to work it out more precisely.

As a final question: is there maybe a way to find an isomorphism in just one step?

Comment: You say $7^4$ a couple of places where I think you mean $7^3$. In particular, in the sentence that begins with "moreover, every polynomial".

Comment: About your final question: depends on what you mean by one step. Of course if you compose all your isos you'll end up with a one-step procedure, but it may be hard to find it in that way. By the discussion on the edit of my answer (which involves many isos), you can just compute the degree of $4x(2x^2)+(2x^2)+1$.

Comment: @Arthur, yes, you're right, I meant $7^3$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very useful trick to remember is that a multivariate polynomial ring is (isomorphic to) an iterated construction of polynomial rings. Namely, in your example, we have

$$
\Bbb F_7[x,y] \simeq \Bbb F_7[x][y].
$$

This is useful because polyomial rings in one variable may be more tractable.

For example: you can show that in general, if $T-\alpha \in A[T]$ is a degree $1$ monic polynomial in a polynomial ring $A$ and $P \in A[T]$ then there always exist unique $Q \in A[T]$ and $R \in A$ such that $P = (T-\alpha)Q+R$.

In particular, for any poynomial $p$ in $\Bbb F_7[x,y]$ there are unique $q \in \Bbb F_7[x,y]$ and $r \in \Bbb F_7[x]$ such that

$$
p(x,y) = (y-2x^2)q(x,y)+r(x).
$$

From this observation you can see that the map $\tau \colon \Bbb F_7[x,y] \to \Bbb F_7[x]$ sending $x \mapsto x, y \mapsto 2x^2$ has kernel precisely $(y-2x^2)$. Thus

$$
\Bbb F_7[x,y]/(y-2x^2) \simeq \Bbb F_7[x]
$$

and by the third isomorphism theorem we get

$$
\Bbb F_7[x,y]/I \simeq \Bbb F_7[x]/J.
$$

Now, you already observe that $J = (x^3+2x^2+1)$ is maximal, hence the latter quotient a field.

Since $\{[1],[x],[x^2]\}$ is a $\Bbb F_7$-basis for $\Bbb F_7[x]/J$ as a vector space, we have $\dim_{\Bbb F_7}\Bbb F_7[x]/J = 3$ and so $|\Bbb F_7[x]/J| = 7^3$. But then by uniqueness of finite fields, it has to be $\Bbb F_7[x]/J \simeq \Bbb F_{7^3}$.

**Edit:** here are some generalizations that use the exact same arguments: if $p = y-\alpha \in R[x][y]$ is of degree one, then $R[x,y]/(p) \simeq R[x]$ for any *ring* $R$, the isomorphism sends $x$ to $x$ and $y$ to $\alpha$.

Moreover, if $g \in R[x,y]$ then its image via this iso is $g(x,\alpha)$ and thus

$$
R[x,y]/(p,g) \simeq R[x]/(g(x,\alpha)).
$$

Fix $d = \deg g(x,\alpha(x))$. Then $\{[1],\ldots, [x^{d-1}]\}$ is a basis of $R[x]/(g(x,\alpha))$ as a free module.

In particular if $R = k$ is a field, then $k[X]/(g(x,\alpha))$ is a $d$-dimensional $k$-algebra, and if $g(x,\alpha)$ is irreducible then it is a field extension of dimension $d$. In that case, some computations follow:

- If $k = \Bbb F_q$ is finite, then $\Bbb F_q[X]/(g(x,\alpha)) \simeq \Bbb F_{q^d}$.
- If $d = 2 \neq \mathbf{char} (k)$, then $k[X]/(g(x,\alpha)) = k(\sqrt{d})$ with $d^2 \in k, d \not \in k$. Indeed, if $g(x,\alpha) = x^2+bc+c$ we have $k[X]/(g(x,\alpha)) \simeq k(\omega)$ with $\omega$ a root of $g(x,\alpha)$ in some algebraic closure, and we can apply the classification of quadratic extensions.

In general, if $R$ at least has the invariant basis property, you can (maybe) distinguish such quotients by looking at the total degree of a polynomial.

Comment: Thanks! This is a very useful answer. Definitely helped.